# Sending only one message per broker on kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using a single cluster multi-broker kafka cluster with spark streaming to fetch data. the problem i am facing is under one topic same message get sent across all brokers.

How do I limit kafka to send only one message per broker so that there is no duplication of messages under one topic?

Comment: Are you partitioning your topic?

Comment: Not as of now but surely going ahead will have to partition it

Comment: Anyone can help me out with this ?